# Как писать адрес на конверте?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно писать адрес на конверте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно последним требованиям адрес пишется в следующем порядке.
В правом нижнем углу письма адрес получателя. Первая строчка: имя, отчество и фамилия получателя. Вторая: улица, дома, квартира. Третья: город. Четвертая: страна. Пятая: почтовый индекс.
Адрес отправителя пишется в левом верхнем углу в том же порядке.
Например:
*И.В. Петров.

ул. Ленина, 7, кв. 8

г. Сыктывкар

Россия

567945*

Внимание: на Украине приняты пятизначные индексы.